# Java - Can't use lambda for self made interface - Target type of lambda conversion must be an interface

Tags: java, intellij-idea, lambda

I have the following code:

```
public interface Logic
{

    boolean logicAccesscible();
}


public class LocationLogic implements Logic
{
    @Override
    public boolean logicAccesscible()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

But when I try to use a lambda to create a LocationLogic object it simply won't work.

```
    l.setLocationLogic(new LocationLogic()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean logicAccesscible()
        {
            return false;
        }
    });
```

that snipet works, but

```
l.setLocationLogic(() ->
    {
        return false;
    });
```

Gives me the error of "Target type of lambda conversion must be an interface"

And yes, I've tried to use:

```
l.setLocationLogic((LocationLogic) () -> {return false;});
```

Comment: It's just a simple setter. public void setLocationLogic(LocationLogic locationLogic)
    {
        this.locationLogic = locationLogic;
    }

Comment: The message is quite clear. A lambda is an instance of a functional **interface**. LocationLogic is a **class**. Make your setter take a Logic as argument, not a LocationLogic.

Comment: So what I have to change is... ?

Comment: Make your setter take a Logic as argument, not a LocationLogic.

Comment: @JBNizet is correct.  If you change the setter argument type from LocationLogic to Logic, it should work as you expect.

Comment: Thanks that worked!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get this error because, you can only create `lambdas` from functional interfaces, which just means an interface with exactly *one* `abstract` method.

Now your `setLocationLogic` expects a `LocationLogic` (a class) and java forbids the creation of lambdas from classes. thats why your first snippet works, but your second doesn't.

Either change the signature of `setLocationLogic` to `setLocationLogic(Logic logic)`.

Or maybe create a constructor in LocationLogic which accepts a boolean, which you then return in the implemented function:

```
public class LocationLogic implements Logic{
    private final boolean accessible;

    public LocationLogic(boolean accessible){
        this.accessible = accessible;
    }

    public boolean logicAccessible(){
        return accessible;
    }
}
```

That way you could use it like:

```
l.setLocationLogic(new LocationLogic(false));
```